# passing special chars as args from python script to shell

Tags: python-3.x, shell, parameter-passing

I have a config_file.yml file like this:

```
sample:
    sql: "select * from dbname.tableName where sampleDate>='2018-07-20';"
    config: {'hosts': [!!python/tuple ['192.162.0.10', 3001]]}

sample2:
    sql: "select * from dbname.tableName where sampleDate<='2016-05-25';"
    config: {'hosts': [!!python/tuple ['190.160.0.10', 3002]]}
```

My python code is:

```
data_config = yaml.load(config_file)
for dataset, config in data_config.items():
    args = [config]
    cmd = ['./execute_something.sh']
    cmd.extend(args)
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()
```

execute_something.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
data_config=$1
echo $data_config
```

So basically I want to pass `{'sql': "select * from dbname.tableName where sampleDate>='2018-07-20';", config: {'hosts': [!!python/tuple ['190.160.0.10', 3002]]}}` this entire string as an argument to the shell script.

Problem:
1) `select *` ends up listing all files in the current directory, instead of being passed entirely as a string
2) even if I pass a simple string say `args="hi"` it still won't work!

I don't understand what I am missing here. Kindly help.
Thanks!

Comment: It's nothing to do with special characters -- you'd have the same problem with this code passing arguments with no special characters at all.

Comment: BTW, you should also be careful about quoting on the shell end of the world -- `echo "$1"` is more correct than `echo $1`. See [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### DO NOT USE `shell=True`.

```
data_config = yaml.load(config_file)
for dataset, config in data_config.items():
    cmd = ['./execute_something.sh', str(config)]
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

---

When you run `shell=True`, you're prepending `sh -c` to your literal argument list. What that does in this case is the following (escaping is added to make the single quotes literal):

```
sh -c './execute_something.sh' '{'"'"'sql'"'"': "select * from dbname.tableName where sampleDate>='"'"'2018-07-20'"'"';", config: {'"'"'hosts'"'"': [!!python/tuple ['"'"'190.160.0.10'"'"', 3002]]}}'
```

That doesn't work. Try it manually in a shell, if you like. *Why*? Because the argument starting with the `{` isn't passed to `./execute_something.sh`, but is instead passed to *the shell executing `sh -c`*.

What *would* work, if you really insisted on keeping `shell=True`? Compare to the following:

```
sh -c './execute_something.sh "$@"' _ '{'"'"'sql'"'"': "select * from dbname.tableName where sampleDate>='"'"'2018-07-20'"'"';", config: {'"'"'hosts'"'"': [!!python/tuple ['"'"'190.160.0.10'"'"', 3002]]}}'
```

Here, the argument just after the `-c` is a shell script that looks at its arguments, and passes those arguments on to `execute_something.sh`.